# Proof-verification: If $T$ is self-ajdoint wih $2$ and $3$ as eigenvalues then $T^2-5T+6I=0$.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, self-adjoint-operators

> Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space with inner product, and $T:V \longrightarrow V$ a self-adjoint operator. If $2$ and $3$ are the only eigenvalues of $T$, then $T^2-5T+6I=0$.

My attempt of proof: since $T$ is self-adjoint, there is a basis $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ consisting of eigenvectors of $T$. If $v_i$ is a vector of that basis,
$$(T^2-5T+6I)v_i = 4v_i-10v_i+6v_i=0$$
or
$$(T^2-5T+6I)v_i = 9v_i-15v_i+6v_i=0.$$

Therefore, as $T^2-5T+6I=0$ on a basis of $V$, $T^2-5T+6I=0$.

Is this proof correct? The question gives as a hint the following theorem:

> Let $A:V \longrightarrow V$ a self-adjoint operator. Then $A=0$ iff $\langle v, Av \rangle=0, \forall v \in V$.

But I didn't use it in my proof...

Comment: I think it's correct; you are basically using that by being self-adjoint, it is diagonalizable, and hence the minimal polynomial split and is square free. This means that it must equal $(t-2)(t-3)$, which gives you what you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the hint:

$$ \langle v_i, (T^2-5T+6I)v_i \rangle=\langle v_i, T^2v_i\rangle-5\langle v_i, Tv_i \rangle+6\langle v_i,v_i \rangle $$

$$=\begin{cases} 4\langle v_i,v_i\rangle-10\langle v_i,v_i\rangle+6\langle v_i,v_i\rangle & \mbox{, eigenv} =2 \\ 
  9\langle v_i,v_i\rangle-15\langle v_i,v_i\rangle+6\langle v_i,v_i\rangle&  \mbox{, eigenv} =2 \end{cases} $$
$$=\begin{cases} 0 & \mbox{, eigenv} =2 \\ 
  0 &  \mbox{, eigenv} =2 \end{cases} $$

So $T^2-5t+6I=0$ because:

> Let $A:V \longrightarrow V$ a self-adjoint operator. Then $A=0$ iff $\langle v, Av \rangle=0, \forall v \in V$.

Comment: It is not enough to show $\langle v,Av\rangle=0$ for basis vectors only! Here you have to use in addition that the basis of eigenvectors is orthogonal.

Comment: To see this, take a symmetric matrix with zero diagonal. Then $\langle e_i, Ae_i\rangle=0$ for all $i$, but $A$ might not be zero